# Sync multiple ajax Add-to-cart buttons on Woocommerce single product

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

My product page is quite long. So I've added at least three Buy Buttons through the page with the ajax shortcode `[add_to_cart id='123']`

After adding the product the View Cart Link is removed with

```
a.added_to_cart.wc-forward {
    display: none !important;
}
```

and just the BUY text is shown like before with

```
.add_to_cart_button.added  {
    display:  inline-block !important;
}
```

I tried to add a checkmark in front of the BUY button, but that didn't work.
I tried:

```
a.ajax_add_to_cart:visited:before {
   content:  "\2713 " !important;
}
```

1)
Is there a way to synac/link these three Add to cart button together.
So, when the first is clicked, the others show the checkmark, too?
I guess the problem is, that the first one has a different class now which is `.added`
and the other two are just `.ajax_add_to_cart`

2) How do I add the checkmark in front of the .added BUY button?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to sync your checkmarks on all add to cart buttons.

1) checkmark inside the button (before the button text)

The CSS rules:

```css
a.added_to_cart.wc-forward {
    display: none !important;
}
.add_to_cart_button.added  {
    display:  inline-block !important;
}
.add_to_cart_button.added:before {
   content:  "\2713\00a0" !important;
}
```

PHP / jQuery *(where you will replace **`37`** by your product ID)*:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'sync_multiple_add_to_cart_buttons' );
function sync_multiple_add_to_cart_buttons() {
    // Only on single product pages for a specific product
    if( is_product() && 37 == get_the_id() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function(){
            $('a.ajax_add_to_cart').each( function(){
                if( $(this).attr('data-product_id') == <?php echo get_the_id(); ?> && ! $(this).hasClass('added') )
                    $(this).addClass('added');
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

2) A checkmark outside before the button (using [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons/check?style=solid))

The CSS rules:

```css
a.added_to_cart.wc-forward {
    display: none !important;
}
.add_to_cart_button.added  {
    display:  inline-block !important;
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'sync_multiple_add_to_cart_buttons' );
function sync_multiple_add_to_cart_buttons() {
    // Only on single product pages for a specific product
    if( is_product() && 37 == get_the_id() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        checkmark = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>&nbsp;';
        $(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function(){
            $('a.ajax_add_to_cart').each( function(){
                if( $(this).attr('data-product_id') == <?php echo get_the_id(); ?> && ! $(this).hasClass('added') )
                    $(this).addClass('added').before(checkmark);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: ah, is there a way to make this work for a normal wordpress page? I've built my product pages not upon woocommerce product pages but on normal wordpress pages... unfortunately your code doesn't work on that kind of pages, right? i swapped the 37 for my product ID but I couldn't make it work...the css for the 1) checkmark worked great though, thanks!

Comment: I only have a few products, so maybe a solution would be to manually creaty a function for each product and fill in the get_the_id by hand? I tried but couldn't make it work... I wasn't sure about the following line in particular:    `if( $(this).attr('data-product_id') == ect...` any help would be appreciated very much